# Mapping bezier control points to d attribute in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to change a path in SVG by manipulating its control points by dragging the corresponding handles on screen.

This means I can use the x/y coordinates of the 4 handles of each segment (i.e.: cubic Bezier curve) of the SVG path as input.

I'd like to use them to alter the "d" attribute of the path.

I can access the "d" attribute either as an array of arrays like this:

```
[["M",637,17], ["C",731,81,752,139,711,178], ["C",631,252,623,347,623,347]]
```

or in its flattened version like so:

```
["M",637,17,"C",731,81,752,139,711,178,"C",631,252,623,347,623,347]
```

The only thing that I can't figure is something that does

```
function dIndex(segmentIndex, handleIndex) {
     // ?????
     return dAttributeArrayIndex
}
```

so I can then do

```
function setdAttribute(segmentIndex, handleIndex, x, y) {
     // etc etc
}
```

which is something that should work like so (if I am not mistaken, index for x coordinate only, y will be x + 1):

```
0 => 1
1 => 4
2 => 6
3 => 8
4 => 11
5 => 13
6 => 15
7 => 18
8 => 20
9 => 22
```

I cracked my head trying to figure this in Excel.

What's the mapping function here? Or is there a better approach altogether that I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can assume that there is one move `M` and the rest are cubic beziers `C`?

Also, you are using two different indexing systems in your question. One with two parameters (`segmentIndex` and `handleIndex`) and one with just an index.  I am going to assume it's the former you want.

Also I am going to assume that `handleIndex` is 0, 1, or 2.

If so, your function will be like this:

```js
function dIndex(segmentIndex, handleIndex) {
  if (segmentIndex === 0) {
    // the Move command
    return 1;   // the index of X for the M(ove)
  } else {
    // a Curve command
    return 4 +                      // the index of the first X in the first C
          ((segmentIndex - 1) * 7)  // seven array entries per curve ('C' + six coords)
          + (handleIndex * 2)       // first X is +0; second is +2; third is +4
  }
}



console.log( dIndex(0,0) );   // M

console.log( dIndex(1,0) );
console.log( dIndex(1,1) );
console.log( dIndex(1,2) );

console.log( dIndex(2,0) );
console.log( dIndex(2,1) );
console.log( dIndex(2,2) );

console.log( dIndex(3,0) );
console.log( dIndex(3,1) );
console.log( dIndex(3,2) );
```

Comment: this doesn't work but I guess it's because I didn't explain myself well. It still got me to the solution though. Should I re-edit the question?

Comment: Glad it helped. It's probably not necessary to edit your question, since the problem seems quite specific to you.